# How do I save Updates/Installed Packages?

Tags: installation, updates, package-management, backup

So I've been messing with thing that probably shouldn't be messed with trying to learn my way around Linux, and I seem to have messed something up. I'm getting a lot of error messages, reduced speed, and crashes, so I'm going to do a clean install.

However, I an using mobile broadband and don't exactly want to use all of it up again re-downloading updates.

Is there any way I can save all the packages installed now with their updates to an external hard drive?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU. Check out this question, it old but it may give you some tips while your waiting on an answer.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For backup of all your GNU/Linux system, use Remastersys

It can make a full system backup including personal data to a live cd or dvd that you can use anywhere and install. It'll create a **ISO** image compressed.

**What happens with drivers?**

Things like the graphics card and other hardware will be configured and setup automatically and you do not have to use identical hardware. But there is a problem with the **Nvidia** and **AMD** proprietary drivers so they will not be available on the live system and will need to be reinstalled after installation of your custom system.

**Size of ISO**

The maximum single file size for the ISO to be set at **4GB** which means the entire compressed.

**Where I can burn?**

The ISO can be easily backed up to a dvd or external portable drive and copied back afterwards.

---

### For save only your updates:

Save all the package, files located in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. And do a backup of the repository indexes, files located in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

Now in the other computer launch **Synaptic** and select: `File->Add Package Downloaded`

[image: screenshoot]

Then search the folder were you put the files and open it, accept all. With your repository indexes you will not have dependency problems.